# Почему webpack devServer не отображает страницу?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, webpack

Всем добрый день!

Делал сборку `Webpack` для того, чтобы разобраться в его работе, и возникла загвоздка с `dev-server`: если я указываю размещение выходного index.html не в корне, а в папке `templates` (для того чтобы все будущие страницы лежали в одной директории) то `webpack` запускается без ошибок и dev-server стартует, но выдает пустую страницу. Уже гуглил и пробовал разные варианты, но проблему пока не решил. Думаю, что не правильно указываю `contentBase` и `publicPath`. Если кто-то может указать на то, где я ошибся, буду признателен.

Вот файлы конфигурации:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
      source: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/'),
      output: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist/'),
}
```

```
const path = require('path');
const paths = require('./paths');

const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require("vue-loader");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin'); // перенести в основной конфик в конце

const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'

module.exports = {

      entry: {
        main: path.resolve(paths.source, './js/index.js')
      },

      output: {
        path: paths.output,
        filename: 'static/js/[name].js'
      },

      optimization: {
        splitChunks: {
          name: 'vendors',
          chunks: 'all',
        },
      },

      module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.js$/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: ['babel-loader']
          },
          {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            use: ['vue-loader']
          },
          {
            test: /\.pug$/,
            oneOf: [
              {
                resourceQuery: /^\?vue/,
                use: ['pug-plain-loader']
              },
              {
                use: ['raw-loader', 'pug-plain-loader']
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            test: /\.((c|sa|sc)ss)$/i,
              use: isDev ? ['vue-style-loader', 'style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader'] : [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
          }
        ],
      },

      plugins: [
        new CleanWebpackPlugin(), // перенести в основной конфик в конце
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: path.resolve(paths.source, './pug/index.pug'),
          filename: './templates/index.html',
          // filename: 'index.html',
          // favicon: paths.source + '/assets/img/favicon.ico',
        }),
        new CopyWebpackPlugin({
          patterns: [
            {
              from: path.resolve(paths.source, 'assets'),
              to: path.resolve(paths.output, 'static')
            }
          ]
        }),
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
          filename: 'static/css/[name].css'
        })
      ]
};
```

```
const path = require('path');
const paths = require('./paths');
const webpackConfiguration = require('./webpack.config');

const { merge } = require('webpack-merge');

module.exports = merge(webpackConfiguration, {
      mode: 'development',
      devtool: 'inline-source-map',
      target: 'web',
      devServer: {
        publicPath: '/',
        contentBase: path.resolve(paths.output, 'templates'),
        // publicPath: '/templates/',
        // contentBase: paths.output,
        // index: 'index.html',
        hot: true,
        port: 8080,
        // open: true,
      },
      module: {
        rules: []
      },
      plugins: []
})
```

Или сама сборка на Github - https://github.com/YuriySN/webpack-starter-project/tree/structure

Answer (score 0):

Укажите `publicPath` в `output`. Полностью это выглядит так:

```
output: {
    path: paths.output,
    filename: 'static/js/[name].js',
    publicPath: '/templates/'
}
```

Из `devServer` уберите `publicPath`. И вообще `devServer` можно полностью удалить – дефолтных настроек полностью хватает. Разве что можно поставить там поддержку HistoryApi – `historyApiFallback: true`.